# [WEBDRIVER - JAVA]Check all ELEMENTS on ALL Pages open

Tags: webdriver, element

Have any method to check alements on ALL pages opened on new tabs?

Like:

```
WebDriver driverT = new FirefoxDriver()
driverT.get("http://www.x.com.br");

--CHECK ELEMENTS -- OK

--IF FIND ELEMENT, CLICK TO OPEN NEW TAB -- OK

--GO TO OTHER TAB -- OK

Robot robox = new Robot();

robox.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robox.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robox.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robox.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);


--CHECK ELEMENTS ON NEW TAB -- // HOW DO THIS?
```

I just need know how to see elements on page tab opened by first page

Answer (score 0):

Once a new tab (or window) is opened, then you need to tell WebDriver to switch to that window.

Before the new window opens, you will want to get the current window handle of the original window:

```java
String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHanlder();
```

Then, perform your actions to will click to open the new window.  Once the window is opened, you will need to get the window handle of the new window.

```java
for (String handle: driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    if (handle != currentHandle) {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        break;
    }
 }
```

Now, WebDriver is focused on the newly opened window, and then you can perform your actions against that window.  To switch back to the original window, you can use:

```java
driver.switchTo().window(currentHandle);
```